# How mongodb chooses the index while executing a query when multiple indexes exists

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, query-optimization

I have a MongoDB collection that stores some test submissions. The highlevel schema looks as follows.

```
{
  "lessonType": "quiz",
  "userId": "639cb6d9513a420026eddca1"
  "courseId": "639cb6d9513a420026eddca2",
  "lessonId": "639cb6d9513a420026eddca3",
  ...some_more_fields

}
```

Now there are two indexes on this collection.

first one:

```
{ courseId: 1, lessonId: 1, userId:1 }
```

Second one:

```
{ lessonType: 1, courseId: 1 }
```

There are only two values for lessonType which are `quiz` and `assignment`.

Now I want to find all the submissions of a particular course which are of type `quiz`.

Sample query:

```
{ courseId: ObjectId("63a2eb428899436daf7eb489"),lessonType: "quiz" }
```

The above query is always considering the first index mentioned above instead of the second one.

In the first index only `courseId` is useful to match but in the case of seond index it can use both `courseId` and `lessonType`.

If it uses a second index the documents that need to be scanned will decrease by 2 times.

**Any suggestions here?**

I have gone through some articles that suggest providing hint while executing queries.

is there any other way?

If the second index is more performant why mongo is not using it by default?

Comment: It's not obvious from the details provided so far that the second index is meaningfully less performant (efficient) than the first. This is especially true if `lessonType` is not particularly selective (which having just 2 distinct values sounds like it might not be). If you really want to do something here then I'd consider putting `lessonId` as the first field in the first index. That would prevent it from being used by the query in question. You would need to take further action if you ever query by just `courseId` without one of the lesson fields (perhaps reverse the second index)

Comment: Upload the `.explain("allPlansExecution")` output for the query if you want to dig further

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB, the Query Planner attempts to select the most efficient execution path for a query by considering multiple factors.

Note that the Query Planner may not choose the index you believe to be the most efficient for several reasons:

1. Selectivity: If 'lessonType' is not selective (i.e., it has very few unique values, as in your case), the Query Planner might deem it inefficient to scan this index.
2. Index order: The order of keys in an index matters. In the first index, `courseId` is the first key, while in the second index `lessonType` is first, which could affect the choice.
3. Underlying algorithms and heuristics: The Query Planner makes its decisions based on complex algorithms and heuristics, which don't always match our human intuition.

As for your question about hints, yes, hinting is a way to manually instruct the Mongo database engine to use a particular index for a query, bypassing the Query Planner's automatic selection process.

But be careful, forcing the use of a specific index using a hint can backfire if not done properly, it might be more efficient for the MongoDB planner to decide. Ideally, MongoDB should be able to automatically select the best index for your query, but this isn't always the case.

If indexing efficiency is consistently an issue, you might want to consider revising your indexing strategy. Perhaps an index like `{ courseId: 1, lessonId: 1 }` or `{ courseId: 1, lessonType: 1}` would better suit your workloads. Remember that every indexing decision is a trade-off between storage space, write performance and read performance.

Here the official documentation that suggest how to use compound indexes

> Index prefixes are the beginning subsets of indexed fields. Compound indexes support queries on all fields included in the index prefix. (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-compound/#index-prefixes)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Query Plans](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/query-plans/) in the docs.

The MongoDB query planner will generate a list of potential execution plans.  In this case it is likely that both indexes will be considered.

It then runs each of the potential plans until:

- one of the plans completes the query
- each plan returns 101 documents
- each plan performs 10,000 units of work.  (I haven't be able to find a clear definition of what this "unit of work" actually means)

Once the test run of each plan is done, it computes a score for each plan based on the ratio of documents returned per unit of work, and assigns bonuses for not having a sorts and for completing the query.

The plan with the highest score is then selected to perform the full query.  If 2 or more plans have the same score, one of the tied plans is selected at random.

Once the plan is selected, that decision is stored in the query plan cache, so the next time a query of the same shape is received, the cached plan can be used without requiring the planning phase.

As noted in the comments, you can use `explain` with the `allPlansExecution` option to see detailed information about each candidate plan considered and their relative performance.